# Iterating through LinkedList but getting error "for-each not applicable to expression type", what is wrong?

Tags: java, foreach, linked-list, trie

I am currently implementing a trie and this is my code so far:

```
1     public class DictionaryDLB{
2 
3         private Node root = new Node();
4 
5         private class Node {
6             private Character val;
7             private LinkedList<Node> next = new LinkedList<Node>();
8         }
9 
10        public void put(String key)
11        { root = put(root, key, 0); }
12
13        private Node put(Node x, String key, int d){
14            if (x == null) x = new Node();
15            if (d == key.length()) { x.val = '$'; return x; }
16            char c = key.charAt(d);
17            for(Node item : x.next){
18                if(c == item.val){
19                    item = put(item, key, d+1);
20                }
21            }
22            return x;
23        }
24    }
```

However, when I try to compile I get this error in the private `put()` method:

`DictionaryDLB.java:17: error: for-each not applicable to expression type
        for(Node item : (x.next)){
                        ^
  required: array or java.lang.Iterable
  found:    LinkedList<Node>
1 error`

I looked up various examples online and it seems like this should work because `java.util.LinkedList` does implement `java.lang.Iterable`. However, it does not and I am stumped. Any help or advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Did you import the right `java.util.LinkedList` ?

Comment: @AmardeepBhowmick Yeah, I just updated the question now to specify that I am using `java.util.LinkedList`

Comment: I tried your code, it works fine for me.

Comment: I figured out the issue. I was importing it through `java.util.*` and not directly as `java.util.LinkedList` I guess that is a no no. A stupid mistake. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was importing `java.util.LinkedList` with `import java.util.*;` Which does not work in this case, apparently. Had to import it directly with `import java.util.LinkedList;`

Comment: This implies that you have another class named `LinkedList` in your package, which takes precedence without the explicit import. It's generally recommended to avoid such name clashes. Without that conflicting type, you can simply use `import java.util.*;`.